# How is the differential form $dx_1 \wedge ...\wedge dx_k$ "intuitively" an oriented $k$-dimensional volume element?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am reading a [paper](http://math.columbia.edu/%7Edlitt/exposnotes/poincare_lemma.pdf) on differential forms. They define it as follows:

> A **differential $k$-form** on a domain $U$ is a continuous, infinitely differentiable map $\omega \colon U \to \Lambda^k (\Bbb{R}^{n \ast})$ where $\Bbb{R}^{n\ast}$ is the dual of $\Bbb{R}^n$ as a vector space.
>
> In particular we may let $x_1,...x_n$ be a basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$ and let $dx_i\in \Bbb{R}^{n \ast}$ be the unique linear map $\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$ that satisfies $dx_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$

It then goes on to make a comment:

> Intuitively, we may consider $dx_1 \wedge ... \wedge dx_k$ to be an oriented, $k$ dimensional volume element

I don't understand this remark. I know $dx$ from calculus is supposed to be an infinitesimal change and I also understand that wedge product is intuitively a way of turning vectors into higher dimensional objects.

But forget about wedge products. I don't understand how $dx$ defined as $\delta_{ij}$ has anything to do with an infinitesimal change.

What is going on here? Why is this abstract definition related to an infinitesimal change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you feed a list of $k$ vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k\in\Bbb R^n$ into the $k$-form $dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_k$ you'll get the *signed volume* of the parallelepiped formed by $v_1',\dots,v_k'$, where $v_j'$ is the projection of $v_j$ into $x_1\dots x_k$-space.

Comment: Actually, I have one really stupid question. Where does the "infinitesimal" come in? You feed in $k$ vectors to the $k$ form and you get a volume, where does infinitesimal come in?

Comment: "Infinitesimal" is a relic from the old-style, or physics-engineering, way of thinking of integrals. If you chop a $k$-dimensional surface into small pieces, the vectors $v_j$ you feed in here will be small vectors :)