# Is wedge product of n-dimension the length/area/volume,... of an oriented set of n vectors?

Tags: differential-geometry

Is wedge product of n-dimension the length/area/volume,... (which can be positive or negative) of an oriented set of n vectors?

It seems to be answered w yes in the post [How is the differential form $dx_1 \wedge ...\wedge dx_k$ "intuitively" an oriented $k$-dimensional volume element?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2342462/577710)

> If you feed a list of $k$ vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k\in\Bbb R^n$ into the $k$-form $dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_k$ you'll get the *signed volume* of the parallelepiped formed by $v_1',\dots,v_k'$, where $v_j'$ is the projection of $v_j$ into $x_1\dots x_k$-space.

But I still don't know why $dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_k$ ($dx_i$ is $dx_{i,p}$, an infinitely small tangent vector at $p \in M_p$) is signed volume.

It seems the wedge product is obtained from tensor product $dx_1\otimes...\otimes dx_k$ (an average of permutations of the latter), where $dx_1,...,dx_k$ is basis of covariant tangent space at $p$ (a collection of maps from a tangent vector $\in M_p$ to a number)--this contradicts the above definition of {$dx_i$} as basis of tangent space, I'm not sure which one is right--and so $dx_1\otimes...\otimes dx_k$ is something like a map of k tangent vectors to a number and therefore a basis (why?) of k-fold tensor product $T_1\otimes...\otimes T_k: V_1\times...\times V_k \rightarrow $a field, where $V_i$ is the domain of tensor $T_i$.

It seems tensor product can be defined both for tensors and tensor spaces.

Since there is obviously some confusion about basic definitions here, I would say this post is not ready as a question. I will work on it later.

---

According to comments I guess $d x_1\wedge \ldots \wedge d x_k$ is either (1) something like a submanifold around $p$, or something between that and volume, or (2) 'a way to measure volume' of submanifold, a function with submanifold $N$ of manifold $M$ as domain and real number (or something else) as image, and it maps a tiny neighborhood of $p$ to its (signed) volume or sth else (an element in image space of the function to be integrated?).

Actually it's consistent with usual meaning of $dx$ in $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow   \mathbb{R}^m$, since there $dx$ (when n = 1) or $dxdy...$ (when n is not 1) can also be regarded as a **function of neighborhoods in $\mathbb{R}^n$** (not function of single points, similar to measure function in probability space of continuous variable, where $P(x)=0$ and $P$(interval) is non zero) and returns a real number (or a m-dim vector, right?) for  a tiny neighborhood of $x$ or point $(x, y, ...)$. Similarly, $dxdy...$ can be of less dimension than n if we study integration on k-dim subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and regard $dxdy...$ as **functions of neighbourhoods in submanifolds**; this corresponds to the case of $dx_i$ for a submanifold of dimension k (simplest example is k =1 when we study integral of a curve on a surface).

The **wedge product and tensor product** are different from usual $dx$ in real functions in that they are not directly volume  but a measure function (the simplest example is $dx_i$ measures the length of a curve --as a manifold or a submanifold--or a neighborhood of a point on the curve; œ), and each $dx_i$ is not necessarily 1-dim! (the simplest counterexample is a 2-tensor that measure the area of any neighourhood on a surface--again, as a manifold or a submanifold).

{[œ]the reason for such indirectness is that lines and surfaces, etc. on a manifold is **curved or more complicated** that we can't describe **displacement** of $x$ (and its resulted displacement of $f(x)$?) simply, which is almost the same reason that we define derivatives of $f$ for manifolds differently but in a way consistent with usual derivative of real functions;

if that's right understanding, then I guess the distinct feature of (at least classical) differential geometry from real functions is that the former involves lots of **measuring**, measuring of displacement of $x$ (say **'curved (non-self closure) edge'**) and of area/volume of a region surrounded by 'curved edges'), i.e. **$n$-cube**

--since a curved edge is not self closure, so we must use finitely many of them to form a closure when dim n > 2, and differential geometries choose to use edges similar to that of **square, cube...** which is in Euclidean (straight-line) geometry, the almost least number of edges we need to form a closure in $n$-dim (we can actually use **triangles and tetrahedra$\dots$** but that in Euclidean space obvious as well as perhaps in manifold will cause difficulty in calculation)--

and of corresponding displacement of $f(x)$, i.e. the derivative (one thing to notice is that we don't define ratio of  displacements of $f(x)$ and $x$ since their is as far as I can think of no such ratio for these curved/complicated displacements, rather we choose to describe derivative as **function of displacement** of $x$) similar to derivatives in $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ as linear transformation (map)}

But if so, for integration over a n-dim manifold, just one $dx_i$ (of dim k, k<=n and is the dimension of submanifold to be measured by $dx_1$) seems to suffice for the measurement, why we need the tensor product or wedge product of several (k) $dx_i$?

Comment: No.  It is more than that, because $v_1\wedge v_2\wedge\dots\wedge v_n$ contains the information on the subspace spanned by $v_1,\dots,v_n$.  It also isn't actually length/area/volume/... because your vector space may not have something that measures length/area/... (e.g., your vector space may not come with a natural norm).

Comment: $d x_i$ is not an infinitely small tangent vector. It is a $1$-form. The object $d x_1\wedge \ldots \wedge d x_k$ is a $k$-form, which means that it can be applied to a system of $k$ vectors $(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$ and the result is a number (the said volume).